# Symplectomorphism and compactness

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry

Let $(M,\omega)$ a simply connected symplectic manifold. Suppose there are symplectomorphism $\phi_k: M\rightarrow M$ such that

1)each $\phi_k$ has unique fixed point in $M$.

2)$\phi_k \rightarrow \text{id}$ in the $C^0$-topology on the group $Symp(M)$ of symplectomorphism of $M$

Show that $M$ is not compact.

I find this question from https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/study/III/2005-06/SymplecticTopology/STsheet4.pdf.

It is very easy if 2) is repleced by $C^1$ convergence. Because $M$ is simply connected and we could identify fixed points of $\phi_k$ with critical points of some functions on $M$ via the Weinstein's neighbourhood theorem.

But current condition is  $C^0$ convergence. How to do it? I have no idea.

Comment: Could you explain the construction of the function in the $C^1$-case?

Comment: @PVAL-inactive I mean if $M$ is compact, we can identify $M$ with the diagonal $\Delta$ in $M\times \bar M$, where $\bar M=(M,-\omega)$. Then apply Weinstein's theorem to $\Delta$ such that there is a symplectomorphism between a neighbourhood of $\Delta$ and a neighbourhood of zero section of $T^*M$. Inparticular, $\Delta$ is identified with the zero section. Identify $\phi_k$ with closed forms $\alpha_k$ if $\phi_k$ is . $M$ is simply connected implies that $\alpha_k=df_k$, and fixed points are indentified with intersection of $df_k$ and zero section, i.e. critical point of $f_k$.

Comment: So aren't you just using the $C^1$ condition to guarantee that the graph of $\phi_k$ is in the neighborhood of the diagonal constructed by Weinstein's theorem. $C^0$ is certainly enough for this, then as $\phi_k$ is a symplectomorphism the graph represents a closed 1-form and the rest of your argument still works.

Comment: @PVAL-inactive No. In fact, $C^1$ is used to guarantee that $\phi_k$ could be identified with $\alpha_k$. I use a lemma, which claims that if an embedding $f: M \rightarrow T^*M$ is $C^1$-close to the zero section, then $f(M)$ is the image of some smooth 1-form.

Comment: It should be the image of a smooth closed 1-form as long as it is a section (i.e. the projection map  $T*M \to M$ restricted to your Lagrangian is one to one. I think that if you write somewhat explicit coordinates for your neighborhood, you should be able to see the graphs of functions are automatically sections in your local coordinates.